# Web servers supporting FastCGI Filters

Tags: fastcgi

I'm in the process of writing a [FastCGI wire protocol implementation in C](https://github.com/AndreLouisCaron/cfcgi) (also exports a higher-level C++ interface for writing application servers) and I've got enough of it completed to perform more thorough testing.

I've recently completed a full FastCGI Authorizer that implements HTTP Basic authentication and I'm testing it against other FastCGI implementations to validate that it works according to [the specification](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html).  However, it seems most gateways (web servers) only support the "Responder" role, a very select few support the "Authorizer" role and I have yet to find one that supports the "Filter" role.

I'm testing the "Responder" role against [NGINX](http://nginx.org/) and the "Authorizer" role against [LigHTTPd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).  I've validated so far that none of NGINX, LigHTTPd and [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) support the "Filter" role.  [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/) and [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) don't seem to support setting a role, so I assume they only support the "Responder" role.

Does anyone know of a web server that supports the FastCGI "Filter" role, or is it a part of the specification that's never been implemented?

Answer (score 3):

[Oracle iPlanet Web Server 7.0.9](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/gfsum/index.html) mentions this:

```
<Object name=<"filter.fcgi">
  Service
    fn="filter-fastcgi"
    app-path="/fastcgi/apps/filter/SimpleFilter.exe" 
    bind-path="localhost:3434"
    app-env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/fastcgi/fcgi-2.4/libfcgi/.libs"
</Object>
```

which clearly mentions `filter` miltiple times, so this one sounds like it would support it.

Comment: Indeed, iPlanet seems to have complete FastCGI support.  I'll give it a try.